# Multiple-partition hard drive on Airport Extreme

Tags: network, hard-drive, airport, partition

Is there a way to have multiple partitions on a hard drive plugged into an Airport Extreme? I have a 3TB hard drive, and would like a 2TB partition for storage, time machine backups (mac formatted), and then a 1TB ntfs formatted for stuff accessible to windows computers. However, if I have more than one partition, the disk doesn't show up at all in Airport Utility or in Finder. Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: What is the partition scheme of the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. According to [Apple Support](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mh15139.html):

> **Time Machine can’t back up to an external disk connected to an AirPort
>   Extreme**, or to an iPod, iDisk, or disk formatted for Windows.

However, the same KB also notes that:

> You can use Time Machine with a Time Capsule, and with USB, FireWire,
>   and Thunderbolt disks. The backup disk can be directly connected to
>   your computer or be on a network. **If the backup disk has been divided
>   into partitions, you can use one of the partitions.**

You just can't have that drive hooked up to the Airport Extreme.

Comment: Hmmm, when it has one hfs+ partition, I can use time machine with it just fine. I remember my pleasant surprise when I hooked it up to the Airport Extreme for the first time and my Mac popped up a box asking if I wanted to use the new disk for Time Machine.
I was afraid the airport didn't support multiple partitions, though.